# Split column into separate columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to split the column1 at dot `.` into two columns and rest of the columns remain same.

Input file:

```
chr21.9411551 7 13 53.8461538461538 7 29 24.1379310344828
```

Expected output file:

```
chr21 9411551 7 13 53.8461538461538 7 29 24.1379310344828
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/\./," ",$1)};1' <file
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^[^.]*\.[^.]*[[:blank:]]/s/\./ /' <file
```